# How to make css-menu independent of the number of menu items?

Tags: javascript, html, css, perl

I want css-menu width would be 100% of parent element.
But, sometimes menu has 4 items, sometimes it has 5 items and I want menu would be independent of this.

Look images. 1 & 3 are ok. Now menu has 100% width, ok for 4 items:
[image: menu with 4 items]
Now too, but -_-:
[image: 5 items, bad menu]

Now all fine for 5 items too (I edited css manualy):
[image: all fine now, this is what i want with 5 elements]

I tried to do this next way:
1) I check if user is authorised 
 
2) I calculate li width (perl),
2) I try to change li width parameter (js)

Perl

```
if ($authorised eq true)
{
   $width = 100/5;
}
else
{
   $width = 100/4;
}
$widthString = $width."%";
```

JavaScript code in perl `print( java here );`

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var li = this.document.getElementsByTagName("li"); 
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) { 
    var status = li[i].style.width="'.$widthString.'"; 
    console.log(li[i]);
}
</SCRIPT>
```

css for li: `width: 25%; float: left;`
css for ul: `width: 100%;`

But it not worked for me.

Can anybody explain me why? And for "css" tag followers. I had doubts. Perhaps it is easier to do via css I just do not know.

Thank you.

p.s.: sorry about non-english menu-items, but it's not neccessary for solving problem :)

Comment: Looks like the 20% (100/5) is never applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox! Its part of CSS3 and it's supported in [all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)!

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/976eh/3/

the HTML:

```
<nav>
    <a>Hello</a>
    <a>World</a>
    <a>Hello</a>
    <a>World</a>
</nav>
```

the CSS:

```
nav {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
}

nav>a {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    background: #dadada
}

nav>a:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #e5e5e5
}
```

Comment: … well, except in older IEs. You can also use `<nav>` instead of `<div class="nav">`! It's part of HTML5 which is supported in all major browsers ;-)

Comment: http://gyazo.com/33e391af450ca99b2bd669e0b568392b.png all work fine now :) thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is best solved inside the CSS. Consider a table with *n* columns:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td> 1 </td>
     <td> 2 </td>
     <td> 3 </td>
         ...
     <td> n </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

You can provide the table with a maximum width. Then with `table-layout: fixed`, the horizontal space is divided equally among all cells. See the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8h5y3/) – insert more cells into the row and see how the space is divided.

But do not (mis-)use tables for this! Instead, you can use the CSS `display` property to assign other elements the behavior of the `table`, the `table-row` and the `table-cell`. Semantic markup is important, after all.

One caveat with this: You should also make sure that you don't insert so many cells that their content overflows. Set minimum widths and control the overflow to guard against this. However, the Flexbox model has better ways to deal with this (e.g. starting another row). See [*devian*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21063766/1521179) for that.

---

A note on your Perl code: `$authorized eq true` does not make any sense: Perl does not have a `true` keyword. This will therefore fail to compile if you put `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of each Perl source file – consider using this safety net in the future. To test whether a variable contains a true value, simply use it in a condition: `if ($authorized) { ... }`. To test whether it actually contains the string `true`, use quotes: `if ($authorized eq "true") { ... }` (this is how your code is currently interpreted by the compiler).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try it if next answer (menu via css) wouldn't help me. Sure, I could use <table>, but simple <ul> and css in my opinion was easier way to do what I need.

Comment: Thanks for points about perl. I will use it in future (if ($authorised) { }). Btw, use strict call 500 Error, don't know why.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav The 500 is to be expected, because `use strict` detected errors and therefore terminated the script. Look into the log file to see what the issues were, and fix them (e.g. declaring all your variables, using quotes where they are needed …). For historical reasons Perl has very lax syntax by default, but you really should `use strict` to restrict yourself to a sane subset of the language when trying to write reliable software.

Comment: `if ($authorised) { for authorised users } else { for non-authorised }`. Am I right? @amon

Comment: @SharikovVladislav yes.

Comment: Hm. Okay. What if I check user authorisation in index.pl script, after that I will load another script (`do './pages/header.pl';`). Can I use this var in this script? @amon ?

Comment: I have another problem. I print $authorised at another page and it is right (true in both pages) but .pl script 'don't see this instruction'. It print menu-item anyway. @amon

Comment: Okay. I will just use every where `'true'` and `'false'` (not just `true` and `false`). It worked for me. Thank you. I think `if($authorised)` check same as `if (defined $authorised) { } `. Right? Anyway, all work fine now. Ty very much. @amon

Comment: @SharikovVladislav (1) It is better to use subroutines and packages to structure your code than to `do "script.pl"` which needs global variables to share data. Subroutines can take an argument list, which is better. (2) `if (defined $x)` and `if ($x)` are not equivalent. There are defined values that evaluate to false, like the empty string `""` or the number zero. A variable is not defined if it was not assigned, or when it was assigned the `undef` value (roughly equivalent to `null` in other languages).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45016/discussion-between-sharikov-vladislav-and-amon)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `li` element is getting the correct width percentage for the quantity of elements you are showing.

If you have 5 elements the `li` width must be 20% ([Example #1](http://jsfiddle.net/d96eN/1/)). If it's taking 25% instead, it creates an overflow and you end up with image #2 ([Example #2](http://jsfiddle.net/d96eN/2/)).

So, your error must be in your perl code. When you check if it's authorized...

Hope this helps.